# Calculating the size of Type 1 error, Type 2 error and power of the test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, binomial-distribution, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

Let $X$ have a binomial distribution with parameter $n=5$ and $P\in [p:p=\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$.

The null hypothesis $H_{0}:P=\frac{1}{4}$ is rejected, and The alternative hypothesis $H_a:P=\frac{1}{2}$ is accepted.

If the observed value of $X_1$, a random sample of size one, is less than or equal to $3$.

Find the size of `Type 1 error`, `Type 2 error` and `power of the test`.

I have no idea to solve the question. I only know that

#### Size of a Type 1 error = Pr[rejecting$H_0|H_0 $is true]

#### Size of a Type 2 error = Pr[not rejecting$H_0|H_0 $is False]

The sign $|$ denotes "given that".

Comment: Hi Cynderella. This sounds like a homework question. If so, could you please add the `self-study` tag? Thank you.

Comment: Adding the `self-study` tag (which you should add) will require you to identify a tag to remove. I'd suggest you don't need *both* `power` and `type-ii-errors` as tags.